# notifyDataSetChanged() to the recyclerView from an outer class

Tags: java, android, json

I have a fragment class as an inner class to my mainActivity class and I've defined a RecyclerView here and this is attached to a SlidingTabLayout. i'm requesting some JSON data and i'm supposed to update this RecyclerView. when i call **ListingsFragment.mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()**  after parsing JSON data in one of the functions in my mainActivity class nothing is happening :(

in my getData() i load the data to the RecyclerView from an ArrayList of Objects to which i copy data after parsing the JSON results earlier.

any help or thought is appreciated. Thanks.

This is my fragment class

```
     public static class ListingsFragment extends Fragment {

        private RecyclerView mListRecyclerView;

        private static ListAdapter mAdapter;


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {



            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listings_fragment, container, false);
            mListRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.listing_recyclerView);

            mListRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new HorizontalDividerItemDecoration.Builder(getActivity())
                    .marginResId(R.dimen.leftmargin, R.dimen.rightmargin)
                    .build());


            mAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), getData());

            mListRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

            return view;
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25102113/1318946

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `setAdapter` again instead of `notifyDataSetChanged`?

**Update:**
This is not just a workaround, may be necessary as far as i know. Looked in to data logic implementation of `RecyclerView`

```
private class RecyclerViewDataObserver extends AdapterDataObserver {
@Override
public void onChanged() {
    assertNotInLayoutOrScroll(null);
    if (mAdapter.hasStableIds()) {
        // TODO Determine what actually changed.
        // This is more important to implement now since this callback will disable all
        // animations because we cannot rely on positions.
        mState.mStructureChanged = true;
        setDataSetChangedAfterLayout();
    } else {
        mState.mStructureChanged = true;
        setDataSetChangedAfterLayout();
    }
    if (!mAdapterHelper.hasPendingUpdates()) {
        requestLayout();
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
    assertNotInLayoutOrScroll(null);
    if (mAdapterHelper.onItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount)) {
        triggerUpdateProcessor();
    }
}
....
```

Layout change depends on `AdapterHelper`'s `UpdateOp` queue, but unlike `onItemRangeInserted`, `onChanged` actually didn't place any `UpdateOP` into the queue, which I guess is not implemented yet (should be written in the                 `// TODO Determine what actually changed.` and split the total change to atomic updates).

**Personally**, there is really not so much performance difference between `notifyDataSetChanged` and `setAdapter` or `swapAdapter`, as almost same amount of UI rendering work should be done (just feel free in object instance overhead compared to onMeasure).

`RecyclerView` is more designed for card-style single operation, so it's better to figure out what actually changed and perform as such `notifyItemRangeChanged(int, int)`

Some other examples also uses `setAdapter` like this one: 
http://javatechig.com/android/android-recyclerview-example

Comment: Usually you wouldn't need to reset the adapter, but you could try it to see if it has any effect to help you debug further.

Comment: right now, i set the adapters and pager after loading the values, this is the only way i'm getting my recyclerView work. I'm sure this method is not efficient coz in the UI there is a bit of lag when i do this way, but the data is loaded.

Comment: Log.v(TAG, "Parsed result Stored...");
         mPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));mTabs.setViewPager(mPager); for now i'm doing this way. these lines of code i've put after parsing the JSON result

Answer (score 0):

Your `mAdapter` was being `private`. You should change it to `public` and comment the result here.

Are you sure that you got the `JSON Object`? Make a `Log` or `Toast` and comment again, please!

P/s: Sorry about my bad English

Comment: Well, i missed that thing, LOL. Thanks anyways. I tried, i made it private but nope my recylerview is still empty :(